# Unix system(“unzip archive.zip”) Extracting Zip Files Silently

Tags: linux, php, webserver, zip, php5

How do I silently extract files, without displaying status?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

man unzip:

```
   -q     perform  operations  quietly  (-qq  = even quieter).  Ordinarily
          unzip prints the names of the files it's extracting or  testing,
          the extraction methods, any file or zipfile comments that may be
          stored in the archive, and possibly a summary when finished with
          each  archive.   The -q[q] options suppress the printing of some
          or all of these messages.
```

Answer (score 10):

From the [unzip man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip):

> **-q**
>
> perform operations quietly (**-qq** = even quieter). Ordinarily *unzip* prints the names of the files it's extracting or testing, the extraction methods, any file or zipfile comments that may be stored in the archive, and possibly a summary when finished with each archive. The **-q**[**q**] options suppress the printing of some or all of these messages.

So `unzip -qq yourfile.zip` it is.

Comment: This answer exists already

Comment: I'm sorry, it did not when I started typing.

Answer (score 2):

PHP has an extension for that

http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('test.zip') === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo('/my/destination/dir/');
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
?>
```

Comment: Well, ZipArchive library and other libraries didn't work for my sever.

Comment: http://pecl.php.net/package/zip

Comment: Tried that too didn't work, had to do a unix function before it worked. Thanks Anyway

Answer (score 1):

I suggest with this is using **gunzip** command

```
gunzip /path/to/file/filename.z
```

this will also output silently